# Hide the content only the two corresponding checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#checkallindus').click(function () {
    if($('#checkallindus').attr('checked',false)){
        $('.cat1').hide();
    }
   });
   $('#checkallpro').click(function () {
    if ($('#checkallpro').attr('checked', false)) {
        $('.cat2').hide();
    }
   });
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
    if ((document.getElementById('checkallindus').checked == false) &&                                                                       (document.getElementById('checkallprod').checked == false)) {
        $('.disp').hide();
    }
    });
   </script>
   <html>
  <body>
<div class="disp">
    Case 1
    <div class="cat1">Industry: Environment</div>
    <div class="cat2">Product: ASP.NET</div>
    <div class="des">The asp.net product in the envirnmen industry</div>
  </div>
  <div class="disp">
    Case 2
    <div class="cat1">Industry: Hobbyist</div>
    <div class="cat2">Product: WinRT</div>
    <div class="des">The Winrt product in the hobbyist industry</div>
  </div>
  <div class="disp">
    <div class="cat1">Industry: Hobbysit</div>
    <div class="cat2">Product: ASP.NET</div>
    <div class="des">The ASP.NET product in the hobbyist industry</div>
  </div>
  <div class="head">Industry</div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkallindus" checked/>ALL
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkindus" checked/>Environment
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkindus" checked/>Hobbyist
  <div class="head">Product</div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkallpro" checked/>ALL
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkpro" checked/>ASP.NET
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkpro" checked/>WinRT
   </body>
   </html>
```

In the code I have written the script for the "ALL" checkboxes but for indivual checkboxes I am unable to write the script. The content under "disp" must be hidden only if the checkbox under industry and also the corresponding checkbox under product is unchecked. Can anyone help me how to write the script in this case.

Comment: put your script on bottom or wrap the javascript with jquery's ready function

Answer (score 0):

I made this, check is it fulfilling your needs or not.

```
   <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
  <body>
<div class="disp">
Case 1
<div class="cat1 env" style="display: block;">Industry: Environment</div>
<div class="cat2 net">Product: ASP.NET</div>
<div class="des">The asp.net product in the envirnmen industry</div>
</div>
<div class="disp">
Case 2
<div class="cat1 hobb" style="display: block;">Industry: Hobbyist</div>
<div class="cat2 win">Product: WinRT</div>
<div class="des">The Winrt product in the hobbyist industry</div>
</div>
<div class="disp">
Case 3
<div class="cat1 hobb" style="display: block;">Industry: Hobbysit</div>
<div class="cat2 net">Product: ASP.NET</div>
<div class="des">The ASP.NET product in the hobbyist industry</div>
</div>
  <div class="head">Industry</div>
<input id="checkallindus" type="checkbox" checked="">ALL
<input class="checkindus" type="checkbox" checked="" id="indEnv">Environment
<input class="checkindus" type="checkbox" checked="" id="indHobb">Hobbyist
<div class="head">Product</div>
<input id="checkallpro" type="checkbox" checked="">ALL
<input class="checkpro" type="checkbox" checked="" id="prodNet">ASP.NET
<input class="checkpro" type="checkbox" checked="" id="prodWin"> WinRT
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#checkallindus').change(function () {
    console.log($('#checkallindus').attr('checked'));
    if($('#checkallindus').attr('checked')){
        $('.cat1').show();
    }else {
    $('.cat1').hide();
    }
   });
   $('#checkallpro').change(function () {
    if ($('#checkallpro').attr('checked')) {
    $('.cat2').show();
    }else{
        $('.cat2').hide();
    }
   });
$("#indEnv").change(function(){
    if($("#indEnv").attr("checked")){
        $(".env").show();
    }else {
        $(".env").hide();
    }
});
$("#indHobb").change(function(){
    if($("#indHobb").attr("checked")){
        $(".hobb").show();
    }else {
        $(".hobb").hide();
    }
});
$("#prodNet").change(function(){
    if($("#prodNet").attr("checked")){
        $(".net").show();
    }else {
        $(".net").hide();
    }
});
$("#prodWin").change(function(){
    if($("#prodWin").attr("checked")){
        $(".win").show();
    }else {
        $(".win").hide();
    }
});

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: the above is just a part of my whole code, same way I have 50 cases and 30 checkboxes. It is not possible to write the change function for each checkbox or for each case. Is there any other method to solve this? Thanks for your reply